# Can not sign in to google in android studio

Tags: android

I tried to sign in to google account using android studio
but for some reason I cannot, the sign in button doesn't work.
I tried to search a solution for this issue but I cannot find it.

this is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
public static final String PROFILE_USER_ID = "USER_ID";
public static final String PROFILE_FIRST_NAME = "PROFILE_FIRST_NAME";
public static final String PROFILE_LAST_NAME = "PROFILE_LAST_NAME";
public static final String PROFILE_IMAGE_URL = "PROFILE_IMAGE_URL";



 private Button SignOut;
private SignInButton SignIn;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private static final int REQ_CODE=9001;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SignOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bn_logout);
    SignIn = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.bn_login);
    SignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    SignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(
            this,this).addApi(
            Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,signInOptions).build();


    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    //loginButton.setReadPermissions("email","public_profile");//to enable see profile

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
        {
            String userLoginId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
            Intent screen2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyGestas.class);
           //Intent gastas = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gastas.class);
            Profile Profile = com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            String firstName = Profile.getFirstName();
            String lastName = Profile.getLastName();
            String userId = Profile.getId().toString();
            String profileImageUrl = Profile.getProfilePictureUri(96, 96).toString();
            loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            screen2.putExtra(PROFILE_USER_ID, userId);
            screen2.putExtra(PROFILE_FIRST_NAME, firstName);
            screen2.putExtra(PROFILE_LAST_NAME, lastName);
            screen2.putExtra(PROFILE_IMAGE_URL, profileImageUrl);
            startActivity(screen2);






            //GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                //@Override
               // public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                   // displayUserInfo(object);
             //   }
           // });

            //Bundle parm = new Bundle();
            //parm.putString("fields","first_name, last_name, email");
            //graphRequest.setParameters(parm);
           // graphRequest.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.bn_login:
            signIn();
            break;
        case R.id.bn_logout:
            signOut();
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
private  void signIn()
{
    Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE);
}
private void signOut()
{

    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}
private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result)
{
    if(result.isSuccess())
    {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        updateUI(true);
    }
    else
    {
        updateUI(false);
    }


}
private void updateUI(boolean isLogin)
{
    if(isLogin)
    {
        SignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        SignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQ_CODE)
    {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleResult(result);
    }
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}
```

}

the GoogleApi is enabled and I tried to add the Metadate to the manifest
The error from the Logcat is this:

```
12-13 13:41:22.457 2442-3481/? E/GmsUtils: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
12-13 13:41:25.000 2391-3507/? E/ScorerSelector: Couldn't find a ranking descriptor in DataLayer__ranking_descriptor flag.
12-13 13:41:45.226 1616-1665/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=6, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
12-13 13:42:04.141 3540-3540/? E/CAR.TEL.Service: Failed to bind to InCallService
12-13 13:42:04.276 2637-2637/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
12-13 13:45:20.890 3699-3699/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:20.890 3699-3699/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:20.907 1616-1649/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '688e807 com.example.matan.ggesta/com.example.matan.ggesta.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-13 13:45:21.459 3709-3709/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:21.459 3709-3709/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:21.802 3728-3728/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:21.802 3728-3728/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:24.527 3742-3742/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:24.527 3742-3742/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:24.535 3740-3740/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:24.535 3740-3740/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:24.825 3764-3764/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:24.825 3764-3764/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:26.016 1334-1339/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
12-13 13:45:39.592 3824-3824/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:39.592 3824-3824/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:39.608 1616-1649/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '63ac971 com.example.matan.ggesta/com.example.matan.ggesta.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-13 13:45:40.105 3835-3835/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:40.105 3835-3835/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:40.474 3854-3854/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:40.474 3854-3854/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:42.954 3866-3866/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:42.954 3866-3866/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:42.962 3868-3868/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:42.962 3868-3868/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:43.378 3891-3891/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-13 13:45:43.378 3891-3891/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-13 13:45:44.539 1334-1369/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property





                                              string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may haven't activated Google+ Api on the console correctly recheck the whole process.

also enable auth

Login here: https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0

Choose your project

Find "APIs and Auth" on the left

Click on API

On this list, you'll see many APIs available.

Hope it works for you.